# How do I vary stroke on a line to create an effect similar to "Ed, Edd, and Eddy"?

Tags: styles, adobe, photoshop, diacritics, stroke

I'm trying to create the "Ed, Edd, and Eddy" art style. Here's an example image: [image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0e/Ed,_Edd_n_Eddy_characters.png]

Specifically, I'm trying to capture the effect of having accent lines with varying stroke values within the same line.

I have access to the Adobe suite. Spent a couple hours trying to see if I could do something in Photoshop or Illustrator to no avail. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use Illustrator, here's a quick tutorial on how it's done in Illustrator CC.

- Draw your starting shape:
  [image]
- Choose the width tool from the toolbox

  [image]
- click anywhere on the path and drag it out to the desired width

  [image]
- Repeat this (you can widen and thin the stroke) until you have the desired result.
  [image]

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop, simply create a brush that is pressure sensitive (= change brush diameter with pressure) with your tablet.
That should give you the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

@user3488148 you are looking for a free form drawing strokes and for that you can use a brush that provides accents while you draw and can respond to pressure (if a tablet stylus is used) as well. Check out for inbuilt brushes and modify their diameter, length, pressure, etc.